# innerHTML firstChild.value works in IE9 IE8 but not IE10, Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The following code works in IE8,9 but not in IE10, Firefox or chrome. 
The calculations are correct in IE8,9 and older versions but in IE10, FF ,chrome the calculated values in the respective columns and rows show up as NaN.
I have provided the entire code. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function enable_text(che, inp, cost) {

         if (che.checked) {
            var c = inp;
            var d = cost;
            document.getElementById('gate_req_' + c).value = d;
         }
         else {
            var c = inp;
            var d = cost;
            document.getElementById('gate_req_' + c).value = 0;
         }
      }
   </script>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="post" name="f1" id="f1">
         <table width='95%' border='1' id='tableId' name='tableId'>
            <tr>
               <td>A</td>
               <td>B</td>
               <td>C</td>
               <td>D</td>
               <td>E</td>
               <td>Cost</td>
               <td>discount yes/ no</td>
               <td>Discount amount</td>
               <td>Subtotal (Cost - Discount Amount)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>J</td>
               <td>K</td>
               <td>L</td>
               <td>M</td>
               <td bgcolor='#F4F4F4'>N</td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>
                  <input name='CourseCost' readonly size='6' value=1600>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='checkbox' name='check_box_[]' value=1819 onclick='enable_text(this,0,1600);calc();  ' />

                  <input type='hidden' name='check_box_uncheck[]' value=1819
                     />
               </td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>
                  <input type='text' name='gate_req_[]' value='0' readonly id='gate_req_0' />
               </td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>&nbsp;   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>O</td>
               <td>P</td>
               <td>Q</td>
               <td>R</td>
               <td bgcolor='#F4F4F4'>S</td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>
                  <input name='CourseCost' readonly size='6' value=1600>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='checkbox' name='check_box_[]' value=1821 onclick='enable_text(this,1,1600);calc();  ' />

                  <input type='hidden' name='check_box_uncheck[]' value=1821
                     />
               </td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>
                  <input type='text' name='gate_req_[]' value='0' readonly id='gate_req_1' />
               </td>
               <td id='enteredValues'>&nbsp;   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td align='left'>Com</td>
               <td align='left'>
                  <input name='Registration_fee' type='text' value='200' size=6 readonly />
               </td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                  <input name='Registration0fee' value='0' size=6 readonly />
               </td>
               <td align='left'>
                  <input name='Registration_fee' value='200' size=6 />
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='columnTotals' name='columnTotals'>
               <td>&nbsp; </td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;  </td>
               <td>&nbsp;  </td>
               <td>= N +S + Com</td>
               <td>
                  <input id='sum1' name='sum1' type='text' readonly>
               </td>
               <td>&nbsp;  </td>
               <td>
                  <input id='sum2' name='sum2' type='text' readonly>
                  = Discount Amount Subtotal
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input id='sum3' type='text' name='sum3' readonly>
                  = Total
               </td>
         </table>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
         var enteredValues = document.getElementById("tableId");
         var inputs = enteredValues.getElementsByTagName("input");
         var columnTotals = document.getElementById("columnTotals");

         (function calc() {
            var col_1_total = 0, col_2_total = 0, col_3_total = 0;//initialise running totals to zero
            for (var i = 1; i < enteredValues.rows.length - 1; i++) {
               var cells = enteredValues.rows[i].cells;
               col_1_total += Number(cells[5].firstChild.value);
               col_2_total += Number(cells[7].firstChild.value);
               col_3_total += Number(cells[8].innerHTML = cells[5].firstChild.value - cells[7].firstChild.value);
            }
            document.getElementById("sum1").setAttribute("value", col_1_total)
            document.getElementById("sum2").setAttribute("value", col_2_total)
            document.getElementById("sum3").setAttribute("value", col_3_total)

         })();//execute calc() immediately to cater for any initial values

         for (var i = 1; i < inputs.length - 1; i++) {
            inputs[i].onchange = calc;
         }//attach calc as onblur handler to input fields.
      };
   </script>

   <script>
      function calc() {
         var enteredValues = document.getElementById("tableId");
         var inputs = enteredValues.getElementsByTagName("input");
         var columnTotals = document.getElementById("columnTotals");
         var col_1_total = 0, col_2_total = 0, col_3_total = 0;//initialise running totals to zero
         for (var i = 1; i < enteredValues.rows.length - 1; i++) {
            var cells = enteredValues.rows[i].cells;
            col_1_total += Number(cells[5].firstChild.value);
            col_2_total += Number(cells[7].firstChild.value);
            col_3_total += Number(cells[8].innerHTML = cells[5].firstChild.value - cells[7].firstChild.value);
         }
         document.getElementById("sum1").setAttribute("value", col_1_total)
         document.getElementById("sum2").setAttribute("value", col_2_total)
         document.getElementById("sum3").setAttribute("value", col_3_total)
      }
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to reduce the size of your example to the smallest possible code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You want firstElementChild, not firstChild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col_1_total += Number(cells[5].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
col_2_total += Number(cells[7].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
col_3_total += Number(cells[8].innerHTML = cells[5].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value - cells[7].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value);
```

`firstChild` is a text node (caused by whitespaces between `<td>` and `<input>`), not the input element you apparently want.

Also, your code is quite redundant and not exactly valid html - calc() is defined two times,  tags on the  level instead of /, a closing  is missing, and so on... please consider rewriting that whole thing.

Comment: It's okay the way `calc` is "defined" twice, because the first time it's not defined - it's immediately executed, not declared in the global scope - so the two functions don't "conflict".

Comment: @Ian that doesn't change the fact that they are redundant.

Comment: I didn't say that. I was just pointing out that defining 2 functions with the same name the way the OP did is fine - technically, immediately executing one doesn't need a name anyways. But you're absolutely right that it's redundant to define a function that does the same thing, twice.